# Django Rest Auth Query Based Authentication token restart

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am building a django application and I am stuck with the following issue. The token has an expiry time and I want to create an api endpoint which if visited refreshes the user token availability.

Due to the nature how I handle the rest of the app, I need to use query based authentication. I implemented this as following:

In my authentication.py:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class QueryStringBasedTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        key = request.query_params.get('auth_token').strip()
        if key:
            return self.authenticate_credentials(key)
        else:
            return super(QueryStringBasedTokenAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)
```

And I have updated the settings accordingly:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'authsys.auth.QueryStringBasedTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Now I saw some question on how to achieve what I desire using the standard header tokens. How would I do that with query based authentication?

Thanks in advance! 
Lukas

EDIT:

This is what I have so far, but I have an error that GET is not allowed when visiting that url. POST method just gives me a 500 error.

```
class RefreshAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
def post(self, request):
    key = request.query_params.get('auth_token').strip()
    try:
        token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
        token.delete()
        token = Token.objects.create(user=serializer.object['user'])
        token.created = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        token.save()
        return Response({'token': token.key})
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        return Response("myError", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Are you talking about refreshing the query based token expiry? 
Best practise is to refresh the token itself than changing the expiry.

Comment: Yeah I would like to to refresh the token itself. Still have not figured it out though. Any ideas?

Comment: So the best practise for such situation is to generate a new token on hitting that api and return it in headers of the response and on the client side use the new token thereafter. Refreshing the token expiry is not a good idea. Refresh the token itself.

Comment: Hey Swapnil, thanks for the tip! Indeed, that's what I figured so far. I am still in a battle with this task, but getting there! Posted my code in the edit of my question.

Comment: `GET` is not allowed as you have written only the `post` method in it. About `500` error I will need the stacktrace. And also paste the code for `ObtainAuthToken`.